# Understanding BIND DNS named.stats Statistics

Tags: dns, statistics, bind, named

I am having difficulty finding information concerning the below statistics which are generated in BIND inside the named.stats statistics report:

```
+Cache Statistics+
cache database nodes
cache database hash buckets
cache tree memory total
cache tree memory in use
cache tree highest memory in use
cache heap memory total
cache heap memory in use
cache heap highest memory in use

+ADB Stats+
ADB stats
Address hash table size
Addresses in hash table
Name hash table size
Names in hash table
```

Thanks

Comment: These are fairly low level datapoints that will probably need a bind hacker to make most sense of. Do you need them explicitely for some reason, or is it just curiosity? Otherwise the statistics are generated from https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/blob/master/bin/named/statschannel.c

Comment: More on the lines of documentation purposes and curiosity. I also would like to know more concerning bucket size statistic under Zone Maintenance Statistics section